# How can Kakashi use Kamui and Chidori so much during the Ninja War

Tags: naruto

At the beginning of Shippuden, Kakashi uses Mangekyo Sharingan: Kamui to teleport Deidara's bombs so it doesn't go off in their faces but Kakashi is then bedridden for a week because using Kamui takes a huge toll on him and sucks up all his chakra. Kakashi also said he could only use his Chidori five times a day at the very most.

After Madara and Obito start the Ninja War, all of a sudden Kakashi can spam Kamui and Chidori and literally nothing happens. I get that Kurama lent him chakra, but Kakashi was spamming stuff way before that aswell, and besides, Kurama didn't give him *that* much chakra.

So how can Kakashi use Kamui and Chidori so much during the Ninja War when before it was apparently so taxing to him?

Answer (score 2):

He spams Kamui's and does get the side effects later.

In episode 418, right before Madara fights Gai. Kakashi mentions to Minato how bad his eyesight has become, and that he needs to get closer to use kamui (on one of the truthseeker orbs). During the fight with Pain we see this as well. When he uses his last kamui, blood flows from his eye due to overuse.

As for the 5 chidori's, that shouldn't be the problem with Kurama's chakra.